# Unknown column happens on select but not update?

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `serial` = ".$_POST['articulo']."";
```

The query above doesnt work, it says "Unknown column 'KM3M34KL43M' in 'where clause'" This is so strange! because im telling it the column is called `serial`...

```
 $sql = "UPDATE `productos` SET `cantidad` = {'".$cantidad."'} WHERE `serial` = ".$_POST['articulo']."";
```

This query, however, works just fine, and the where clause is the same

Comment: what is the point of your `.""` thing?

Comment: var_dump your first `$sql`and `$_POST['articulo']`

Comment: You need some single quotes around the string. Also, look into using prepared queries with variables, because you have a SQL injection ready to happen.

Answer (score 1):

If `serial` of text type, then you have to quote the value, so instead of

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `serial` = ".$_POST['articulo']."";
```

it should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `serial` = '".$_POST['articulo']."'";
```

**HOWEVER**, your code is vulnerable to SQLInjection, so you have to escapoe the value as passing user provided data without that is wrong. See methods like `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and use it on your `$_POST['articulo']` while building the query.

Answer (score 0):

Might be just a typo, but I think you have to enclose in single quotes the value returned by `POST`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `productos` WHERE `serial` = '".$_POST['articulo']."'";
```

Comment: it was escaped originally, im just trying simpler stuff to make it work, so far none of the answers work :/